# « Figurer » pour signifier « imaginer » ?

Tags: sens, verbes, verbes-pronominaux

Est-il d'usage d'employer le verbe [*figurer*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/figurer) non pronominal pour signifier *imaginer* (plutôt que [*se figurer*](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/20157) pour essentiellement *s'imaginer*) ; *être la représentation* ou autrement peut-il signifier *(s')imaginer* ?

Comment: Grand amateur de la forme réfléchie du verbe *imaginer* (je n'utilise quasiment qu'elle) j'ai eu posé ce genre de question à des spécialistes / professionnels du **dessin** dans le cadre de la pertinence du label *non-figuratif*... Si ce que j'ai pu retenir de leur réponse vous intéresse, je veux bien essayer de la reconstruire.

Comment: @aCOSwt Oui, bien il ne faut pas hésiter à répondre, merci !

Comment: Des exemples de phrases dites par vous ou par des autres seraient bienvenues ici.

Comment: @Lambie « Par des autres » est très [rare](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=par+des+autres%2Cpar+d%27autres&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpar%20des%20autres%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpar%20d%27%20autres%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cpar%20des%20autres%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpar%20d'%20autres%3B%2Cc0) ou dans la vieille langue. C'est « par d'autres ».

Comment: @Lambie Il ne peut pas donner d'exemples car sa question est fondée sur l'idée que dire « Allez vous le figurer ! » serait un anglicisme, c'est tout. Ça provient de ce commentaire : https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/40442/conveying-the-idea-of-go-figure#comment81373_40444

Comment: @LPH Merci de fournir le lien. C'est en effet lors de notre échange que l'idée m'est venue, comme je l'avais suggéré d'ailleurs. Bien oui, si c'est _figurer_ pour trouver une solution c'est un anglicisme, ensuite bien comme on l'a vu il faut distinguer _allez-vous figurer_ et _allez vous figurer_. Je parle la langue, je ne me suis jamais posé cette question. Il n'est pas toujours nécessaire de produire des exemples, une question plus abstraite permet de réfléchir à la sémantique du verbe, d'identifier les faux-amis sans se faire opposer que telle phrase oui et telle autre non blabla.

Answer (score 1):

*Imaginor enim qui concursus, quae admiratio te...* (1)

**A/ Régler le cas du pronom réfléchi**

- **A1 : Avec *imaginer*... c'est une question de forme.**

*Imaginer* est, au XIIIe, directement piqué au latin impérial *imaginari*.
Et cet *imaginari* appartient à une classe très très particulière de verbes latins : les **déponents**. (on laisse tomber ? ;-))
C'est encore à dire des verbes qui, bien que de **sens actif** n'ont pas de conjugaison à l'actif. Ils **ne** s'utilisent donc **qu'au passif**.

Il ne s'agit pas là d'un caprice linguistique, on peut facilement observer que ces verbes représentent des activités qui émanent du sujet ou qui le concernent, qui soulignent l'**intériorité du sujet par rapport au procès**.

L'*imaginer* français porte donc tout seul cette intériorité. Pas besoin d'adjuvant complémentaire... le sens est sauf!
Le sens mais... pas la forme. Vers la mi-XVIe, on réalise le besoin de restituer à ce verbe (et d'autres déponents) sa **forme** passive... par le truchement... de la **forme** pronominale ***s'*** imaginer.

Ainsi, les meilleurs traducteurs du XVII rendront-ils la phrase de Pline (le jeune) par laquelle cette contribution débute en commençant par : *Je **me** représente / Je **me** figure / Je **m'** imagine*.

Comme d'accoutumée, l'usage commun, il s'en tape de la forme, seul le sens importe et cette forme pronominale va disparaître... quoique... curieusement non... sera (mi XVII) affectée à un tout autre sens.

En conclusion donc pour l'usage commun :

J'imagine = Je **m'** imagine ; j' **ai** imaginé = Je **me suis** imaginé.

Et si on veut un pronom, ce n'est qu'en tant que vulgaire COD :

Je m'imagine = J'imagine moi - Je t'imagine = J'imagine toi

Ce n'est qu'une question de forme donc, sans la moindre atteinte au sens porté par *imaginer*, en particulier le fait que l'image, le résultat du process, **est et reste intérieure au sujet**.

- **A2 : Avec *figurer*... c'est une question de sens.**

*Figurer* calque (vers XIIè) le très classique et très ordinaire *figurare* latin aussi couramment employé avec un pronom explicite (***sibi*** figurare) au sens de *concevoir / se représenter*).

*Figurer* est donc très actif et dans le concret. *Figurer* c'est **faire** une figure, **produire** une forme... et, si on veut signifier que cette figure restera dans sa Ford intérieure, reste dans le virtuel de la pensée alors il faudra être explicite : ***SE*** figurer.

En conclusion de cette partie A/ et donc, consécutivement à l'analyse de la raison d'être du pronom, on peut donc dores et déjà affirmer qu'on ne peut (raisonnablement) employer *figurer non pronominal* pour *imaginer-pronominal-ou-non* puisque *imaginer* porte le sens d'image intérieure au sujet quand figurer-non-pronominal porte au contraire le sens de figure concrète produite par le sujet.

Au mieux pourrait-on, jusqu'ici accepter un ***se*** figurer mis pour *imaginer-pronominal-ou-non*)

**B : Que peut-on (s') imaginer ?**

TOUT! A absolument tout! Un verre rempli d'excellent Whisky certes, mais aussi un cm² à l'échelle 20 d'un monochrome de Klein, sans compter... **et de préférence** (sinon cela ne présente guère d'intérêt)... tout ce qu'évidemment je ne saurais dire avec des mots, tout ce que... je ne sais pas **penser**.

Les romains l'utilisaient déjà dans ce sens très large pour évoquer leurs rêves, des fantômes...

**C : Que peut-on (se) figurer ?**

QUELQUE CHOSE! Nécessairement quelque chose. *Figurer* c'est **représenter**, donner une forme. Je crois que les romains l'utilisaient aussi relativement à la réalisation des statues.
Et au même titre que de bons auteurs ont assuré que toute conscience est conscience **de quelque chose**... toute représentation est une représentation **de quelque chose**.
Ce quelque chose n'est pas nécessairement concret. On se figure tout aussi bien la piéta qu'une branche hyperbolique de direction asymptotique y=ax.

Mais, stricto sensu, on ne peut se *figurer* une toile de Jackson Pollock!
Et pour la simple et bonne et suffisante raison que les toiles de Jackson Pollock sont (voulues) : non-figuratives. Il n'est d'ailleurs qu'à considérer le processus de réalisation pour comprendre qu'il ne peut en aucun cas participer à la réalisation d'une figure, représenter le moindre quelque chose.
Une toile de Jackson Pollock, on ne peut que se... l'imaginer.

---

L'image étant en quelque sorte hypéronyme de la figure, l'utilisation de *(s')imaginer* en lieu et place de *se figurer* apparaît, bien que moins précise, parfaitement légitime. C'est au demeurant le chemin qu'a emprunté l'usuel commun duquel, hormis quelques locutions quasi-figées, *se figurer* me semble sorti.

Mais pour l'inverse (utiliser *se figurer* en lieu et place de *(s')imaginer*)... hé bhé... ça ne le fera qu'à la condition que l'objet de l'imagination soit figurable, figuratif. Puis-je *me figurer* l'univers avant t = 0 ? Non! Puis-je (me) l'imaginer ? Sans problème! (ça peut tout de même dépendre du nombre de verres.)

*... quo ego, quum dico, vel recito, non minus quam clamore delector...* ;-)

---

<sup>1 : Je ne continuerai pas... ceux qui ne lisent pas (il en est ici) penseraient que je fais encore mon cabot.</sup>

Comment: "si on veut signifier que cette figure restera dans sa Ford intérieure" Pourriez-vous m'expliquer le sens de cette phrase? Merci.  Je ne connais que "son for intérieur"

Comment: @Lambie Il veut peut-être évoquer le fait que le for intérieur est une masse mouvante de jugements (posée sur cette immense masse mouvante qu'on nomme notre « for intérieur », où l'on peut trouver tout ce qu'on veut — voir ex; TLFi), mais je crois que son jeux de mots est un peu tiré par les cheveux ou même complètement gratuit.

Comment: @Lambie : Pardonnez-moi je vous prie. A cet instant de mon exposé j'ai ressenti le besoin de chercher la complicité du lecteur... de vous donc... qui ne savez pas ce que je peux bien vouloir signifier avec ce truc et qui donc... allez devoir... vous... ?

Comment: @LPH : Vous avez faux sur un point : La gratuité. Votre commentaire prouve que cela ne l'était pas puisque... avec vous... ça a marché. Bon... j'aurais certes préféré un autre verbe que l'*évoquer* que vous utilisez mais... ne faisons pas la fine bouche. Quant à votre histoire de masse mouvante... hé... en fin de compte... pourquoi pas ? Ce n'est pas plus bête qu'autre chose et comme... vous êtes entièrement libre dans cet exercice.

Comment: @aCOSwt N'hésitez pas à faire la fine bouche, ça ne me dérange pas  outre mesure de ne pas avoir le mot juste et pas du tout de l'apprendre. J'ai bien lu et relu votre étude mais malheureusement ça n'est toujours pas suffisant pour m'en faire une opinion trop claire, bien qu'ayant passé  auparavant un assez long moment sur ces concepts dans la rédaction de ma propre réponse.

Answer (score 0):

Cela ne me semble vrai qu'en vertu de l'admission d'un usage peu courant, et de plus en s'en tenant à cet usage, d'un sens particulier du verbe qui veut que son sujet ne soit pas l'agent de l'action d'imaginer mais le provocateur de cette action ; cela dit, on peut comprendre que l'emploi de cette syntaxe revient à formuler un acte d'imagination par la personne incarnée par le coi du verbe. Donc, dans le cadre de ces « contorsions », oui on peut faire « dire » « imaginer » à « figurer » mais c'est aller chercher un peu trop loin, il me semble. Pour se rendre compte de ce qui est affirmé il suffit de s'arrêter sur la définition suivante du verbe dans le [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/figurer).

> B. [Correspond à figure II]¹
>   1. Donner, d'un élément, une représentation au naturel ou conventionnelle qui en rende perceptible (surtout à la vue) l'aspect ou la nature caractéristique, et à la limite, l'existence particulière.
>   c) Domaine de l'esprit. Susciter à l'esprit l'image de quelqu'un ou de quelque chose.
>   [Le suj. désigne une opération de l'esprit]
>
> • À chaque coup frappé à sa porte, son imagination troublée lui figurait des patriotes armés de piques venus pour l'arrêter (FRANCE, Vie littér., 1888, p. 201).
>   • La rêverie d'Augustin lui figura des ruisseaux élémentaires à la surface mollie des neiges (MALÈGUE, Augustin, t. 2, 1933, p. 360)

¹ <sub>figure II. :  Représentation d'un élément, impliquant une similitude d'aspect (ou, plus généralement, de nature) suffisamment perceptible (par la vue ou par l'esprit) entre les éléments particuliers dont l'un constitue, ou est conçu comme constituant, la représentation de l'autre</sub>

Comme apparemment aucune des définitions traditionnelles de « figurer » en tant que verbe transitif ne s'approche de celle d'« imaginer » plus exactement que ce qui a pu être constaté ci-dessus, force est de conclure que non, il n'y a pas vraiment d'usage courant de « figurer » qui soit celui d'« imaginer ».

Éclaircissements de la réponse ci-dessus en rapport avec le commentaire suivant de user **0one**

1/ La première phrase est vraiment difficile à comprendre et mériterait d'être découpée en plusieurs.
2/ La conclusion. Bien comme tu sais j'ai lié au TLF donc j'ai lu. Je ne trouve pas très très concluant le fait ne pas retrouver quelque chose au dictionnaire, mais bon, c'est peut-être un signe.
3/  J'aurais aimé comprendre comment « penser que quelque chose est la représentation de » est ou n'est pas imaginer en fait.
4/  L'une ou l'autre de ces questions t'amènent-elles à changer d'avis dans ton emploi avec la question de « go figure » ?

1/ Ce n'est vrai que si l'on considère un usage peu courant et dans cet usage si en plus on accepte la syntaxe inhabituelle « sujet-verbe-cod-coi » avec le fait d'imaginer étant imputé au sujet.
 2/ C'est un fait, il pourrait exister un usage naissant, il y a une petite chance de cela.
3/ Si l'on considère que cette mise en relation de concepts revenant à « imaginer », —parce qu'elle revient bien à cela quoi que l'on pense de la façon de le dire— est acceptable au vu des relations directe directes, simples, que l'on pourrait escompter, alors cela est vrai selon cette particularité donnée dans la définition : *le suj. désigne une opération de l'esprit* ; dans les exemples du TLFi ce type d'opération est « son imagination » et « la rêverie d'Augustin ». Cette imagination qui donne une représentation » c'est la personne qui imagine, cette rêverie qui « représente quelque chose» c'est Augustin qui imagine; il ne faut pas aller chercher plus loin.
 4/ Non, je ne vois pas le rapport : il y a l'anglicisme, apparemment limité au Québec, mais il est en plus; la forme pronominale bien établie est tout ce dont il est question dans des formes telles que « Allez vous le figurer ! » et savoir si elle ne fait pas partie de la langue française ne doit pas  impliquer autre chose que le français (Y a-t-il des occurrences ?, La construction est elle justifiable sur la base du principe des assemblages libres ?).

Comment: La première phrase est vraiment difficile à comprendre et mériterait d'être découpée en plusieurs. La conclusion. Bien comme tu sais j'ai lié au TLF donc j'ai lu. Je ne trouve pas très très concluant le fait ne pas retrouver quelque chose au dictionnaire, mais bon, c'est peut-être un signe. J'aurais aimé comprendre comment « penser que quelque chose est la représentation de » est ou n'est pas _imaginer_ en fait. L'une ou l'autre de ces questions t'amènent-elles à changer d'avis dans ton emploi avec la question de « go figure » ?

Comment: @0ne1 Après un avertissement des modérateurs de ne pas utiliser de longs commentaires à la suite les uns des autres, je ne peux que placer une réplique dans ma réponse, ce que je viens de faire.

Comment: "oui on peut faire « dire » « imaginer » à « figurer » mais c'est aller chercher un peu trop loin." Je suis d'accord, dans la mesure que si l'on imagine qlch plus cela figure dans notre imagination. Il y a quand même un saut à faire...

Comment: @Lambie Malheureusement je ne vois pas ce que vous avez en tête, je suspecte que ce ne soit pas juste. Je ne vois qu'une chose dans mon raisonnement : comme le dit le dictionnaire, *le sujet désigne une opération de l'esprit*, ce qui est (on le vérifie dans les exemples) *l'imagination* ou encore *la rêverie* ; c'est cela qui figure, donc ce qui est figuré est, sans réserve, un produit de l'imagination ; donc,  par un truchement, on exprime « imaginer » au moyen de « figurer ».

Comment: [soupir] Je suis d'accord avec vous. Cad, on doit faire un saut (de l'imagination) en plus pour lier figurer et imaginer. Dans un premier temps, "figurer" et "imaginer" ne se substitue pas l'un pour l'autre.

Comment: @Lambie Je vois maintenant : ce que je découpe en stages logiques ( A==> B ==> C ==> …) vous le percevez plus ou moins intuitivement et c'est ce que vous appelez un saut ; de façon imagée on peut appeler ça un saut, bien sûr. En fait il faut que dans la lecture un véritable saut prenne place parce qu'il n'est pas question de s'arrêter avant d'arriver au bout de la phrase pour analyser un processus et quelque chose prend place dans l'esprit qui doit remplacer toute cette logique, laquelle n'est alors d'aucun secours ; c'est peut-être même de ce véritable saut dont vous voulez parler.